# Stack Operation in Python

Tags: python, stack

I am trying to implement the basic stack operation.

The thing is i need the loop to continue asking for entering the choice and want to continue executing until i enter numbers other than 1,2,3.
When  i run this code, after entering the choice 1, it calls the if statement again and again. I want the if statement to stop after calling the function once, until i call it again.I know the code is somehow messy, i only want the basic implementation of stack operation.

```
def create_stack():
    stack = []
    return stack

def check_empty(stack):
    return len(stack) == 0

def push(stack, item):
    stack.append(item)
    print("Item pushed")

def pop(stack):
    if check_empty(stack):
        return "Stack is empty"
    return stack.pop()


def display(stack):
    for i in stack:
        print(i, end = ' ')


def stack_op():
    while True:
        choice = int(input("Enter the choice "))
        while choice < 4:
            if choice == 1:
                item = int(input("Enter the item :"))
                push(stack, item)
            elif choice == 2:
                pop(stack)
            elif choice == 3:
                display(stack)  
            else:
                break
    return False

stack = []
stack_op()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `while` loop is unnecessary and repeats running the same if-block without asking for new input.

Just remove the whole `while choice < 4:` statement and dedent the if-block below. Then, it works. Alternatively, you can include a `break` in each if-and elif-command block to terminate the unnecessary while-loop once you processed the input.